# Java android output from chatgpt in commercial use

Tags: java, android, chat-gpt-4

I have one Question Can I use a generated code from chatgpt for commercial use ?
If so, what do I have to do to be able to use the generated code ?
I try ask help desk but I do not have an answer and I can not find answer in terms of use

Comment: Will OpenAI sue you if you do? No (see [Ownership of content](https://openai.com/policies/terms-of-use) ). What if someone else sues you? Business customer ? yes: [chapter 10. indemnification](https://openai.com/policies/business-terms) no: good luck.

Comment: The above is intended as material for self-study and not legal advice. If you are interested in legal advice, find an actual lawyer.

Comment: @teapot418 so if I can use an outputs because I am a owner Yes ? And how I can thank you for help ?

Comment: @teapot418 Business customer  can sues me ?

Comment: Anyone can sue you for anything. The indemnification (OpenAI will assist in your defense) applies to you if you are a business customer of OpenAI.

Comment: @teapot418 but when I am not a  business customer ?

Comment: Then the "good luck" part applies to you. AI generation vs copyright is a largely untested area of law, no idea how the courts would approach it. I would not personally volunteer to become a test case.

Comment: @teapot418 I talk with desktop and they write me that I can use a outputs it is my own whether generated on a free or paid plan and I can use it for commercial use

Comment: Believability hierarchy: `random people on the internet < openai helpdesk < openai terms of service < openai terms of service reviewed by a lawyer you are paying for`. Anyway, you can find who the terms apply to at the start of the page. You can use that to make your own judgement.